# How to add layouts to ViewPager element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have several swipe style pages and I want to set layouts of the pages. How do I do that?
I tried to skip adding layout and grammatically add a View and before that I just tired adding layouts and views directly in visual app GUI editor.

Comment: Are you using fragments for each ViewPager page? Or what are you using?

Comment: ViewPager is hosting all the sections content and I have SectionsPagerAdapter for managing the section fragments.